# How to show this identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose $A,B,A+B$ are invertible matrices (or just elements of some arbitrary, possibly  non-commutative unital ring). I know that we have:
$$
(A-A(A+B)^{-1}A)^{-1}=A^{-1}+B^{-1}
$$
This is easy to check by direct calculation.

The question is, how can I reasonably arrive at the simplified expression on right hand side without knowing it in prior, or at least reasonably guess so that it makes sense to check it? If it helps, I can assume that $A,B$ commute.

Comment: Hint: take inverses on both sides and use [this identity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36301/proof-of-matrix-identity).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is to make appear $A+B$, in order to simply it with the most problematic term, namely, the inverse of the sum:
\begin{align}
(A-\color{red}A(A+B)^{-1}A)^{—1}&=(A-\color{red}{(A+B)}(A+B)^{-1}A\color{red}{+B}(A+B)^{-1}A)^{-1}\\
&=(B(A+B)^{-1}A)^{-1}\\
&=A^{-1}(A+B)B^{-1}\\
&=(I+A^{-1}B)B^{-1}\\
&=B^{-1}+A^{—1}.
\end{align}

It will work in any non-commutative ring, and we don't need to assume $A$ and $B$ to commute.

Comment: Clever (+1). Maybe I will use it in my class.

Comment: I thought of something like that, but couldn't quite get a hold of it. Thanks. :)